# Stored Procedures and Prepared Statements ins PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Could you please help me with this:
I'm coding PHP and have created a stored procedure in MySQL that receives two input values and return one output parameter

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `ejemplo`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_sp`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_sp`(
    IN ID VARCHAR(8),
    IN Nombre VARCHAR(50),
    OUT msg VARCHAR(50)
    )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO empleado_php VALUES (ID, Nombre);
    SELECT "Todo bien" INTO msg;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and call this via mysqli, everythings works just fine if I use the code snipped below

```
if (!$mysqli->query("SET @msg = ''") ||
    !$mysqli->query("CALL insert_sp('" . $id . "', '" . $nombre . "', @msg)"))
     echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

 if (!($res = $mysqli->query("SELECT @msg as _p_out")))
      echo "Fetch failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
```

and show the output value with this:

```
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['_p_out'];
```

My question is: How am I suppose to code if I have to use prepared statements? could you please give me an example...this is what I' got so far but doesn't work

```
if (!$mysqli->prepare("SET @msg = ''") ||
         !$mysqli->prepare("CALL insert_sp(?,?,@msg)"))
     echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

  if (!($res = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT @msg as _p_out")))
     echo "Fetch failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;

  if(!$mysqli->bind_param("ss", $id, $nombre)){
         echo "Error en bind-param ingresar_sp.php " .$mysqli->connect_error;
     }

    $mysqli->execute();

    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row['_p_out'];
```

By the way...I need to show the output value via echo.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very easy, PHP oficial website remarks that you've got to use session variables (MySQL sessions, not PHP), so, the answers to my question is show below:

```
// bind the value of the first IN parameter to the session variable @id     
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();

// bind the value of the second IN parameter to the session variable @nombre
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @nombre = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $nombre);
$stmt->execute();

//bind the value of the OUT parameter
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SET @msg = ''");
$stmt->execute();

// execute the stored Procedure
$result = $mysqli->query('call insert_sp(@id, @nombre, @msg)');

// getting the value of the OUT parameter
$r = $mysqli->query('SELECT @msg as _p_out');
$row = $r->fetch_assoc();                       

echo $row['_p_out'];
```